# SQLite: Prevent fragmentation

Tags: database, performance, sqlite, optimization, data-structures

I need to fill a database with millions of records, and my current routine for that looks something like:

```
For I = 1 to 10000000
     INSERT INTO TABLE1 ...
     INSERT INTO TABLE2 ...
     INSERT INTO TABLE3 ...
Next
```

I noticed that the records also appear in this order (alternating) in the database file on disk. Would there be a performance improvement when I do this:

```
For I = 1 to 10000000
     INSERT INTO TABLE1 ...
Next

For I = 1 to 10000000
     INSERT INTO TABLE2 ...
Next

For I = 1 to 10000000
     INSERT INTO TABLE3 ...
Next
```

Or doesn't it matter for query-performance how the data is structured on disk?

Comment: Why don't you just import a csv (or tsv, etc) file into the table?

Comment: @JackManey Because the source data is not in that format. It would be easy to convert it to CSV, but how can I import it without writing it to disk (the bottleneck) first?

Comment: If you're inserting the records into a SQLite database, then you **are** writing them to disk.  Why not make it easier on yourself by writing the records to disk and then importing in one batch (or, if necessary, write some of the records to file, import it, and repeat in smaller batches)?

Comment: @JackManey When I first dump them to an CSV file, i'm writing them **twice** to disk? I'm using a transaction, prepared statements, and all kinds of PRAGMA statements (synchronous=off,journal_mode=off) to speed up this bulk import, so what kind of magic does the CSV import code use to beat that speed?

Comment: Well, where are you getting these ten million records in the first place if not from a file?

Comment: @JackManey From a network connection, and I can only insert them after they have finished downloading (because I have to insert them in reverse order), so the network is not the bottleneck, the disk access is.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I had mistakenly assumed that you were reading them from a file (especially given the last sentence in your question).  Since SQLite seems to handle single-row inserts reasonably well (especially with the tweaks you've done), I agree with Parkyprg's answer below:  the latter approach will probably be negligibly faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the second approach you will gain some tiny little performance, if you care that much to take it in consideration. But it depends on the physical disk, how much is the fragmentation.

I think you should focus on optimizing your database and queries.

Comment: You're right, however I spend months optimizing the structure and the queries, so now it's time to move on ;)